# #java HashMap and input

Tags: java

I have a problem with imput some values in a hashmap, 
the `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>` must contain the name and the relative points.I'm not able to put more values for a key.
The input file is the following.

```
Marco,Matteo,Luca,Giovanni;34,35,3,35
Marco,Anna,Chiara;1,5,6
```

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: What do you mean by "relative points"?

Comment: Just use a `HashMap<String, Integer[]>`

Comment: Marco,Matteo,Luca,Giovanni;34,35,3,35

Comment: First name first number and so on

Comment: I have voted to close this question because you have not actually asked a question.  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: the question is implied how to put more values for the same key without subscribing it, the input file has two lines

Comment: You still should show your best attempt with your question and tell what problems you're having with it.

Answer (score 1):

A map doesn't accept duplicate keys.

You could switch to using either a list of maps (One map per row):

```
List<Map<String, Integer>> records = ...
Map<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>(), 
    map2 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("Marco", 34);
map1.put("Matteo",35);
//put values for Luca,Giovanni...
records.add(map1);
//create and add maps for other rows
```

OR a map of lists/arrays (one list per column)

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> map1 = new HashMap<>()
List<Integer> marco = ...
marco.add(34);
marco.add(1);
map1.put("Marco", marco);
//do the same for other records...
```

Comment: In what situation would a list of maps make more sense than a map of lists?

Comment: Unfortunately the program must be able to read every file with that structure. I wrote this code but I can't figure out how write the last part it doesn't subscribing the key

Comment: { String [] name = line.split(";")[0].split(",");
          ArrayList<Integer> p = new ArrayList<Integer>();
          for(int i =0; i<name.length;i++)
           p.add(Integer.parseInt(line.split(";")[1].split(",")[i]));
          ArrayList<Integer> st = new ArrayList<Integer>();
          for(int i =0; i<name.length;i++)
          st = h.get(name[i]);
        if (st == null) {
          for(int i =0; i<name.length;i++){
          st = new ArrayList<Integer>();
          st.add(p.get(i));
           h.put(name[i], st );
         }

Comment: It will depend on how you'll be using the data. If you'll typically be finding all the numbers for Marco, then a map of lists is appropriate. But if your use is record or row oriented, such as, I want the sum of all numbers on second round, then the other option fits better. I'm guessing use cases here...